# On Prime Numbers which can be Norms of an Integral Ideal of a Number Field

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

We know that since the ring $\mathbb Z [i]$ of Gaussian integers is a Principal Ideal Domain, the only integer primes which can norms of some ideal of $\mathbb Z [i]$ are those which can be expressed as a sum of two squares, which by Fermat's Two Square Theorem, are $2$ and the primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. I was wondering what happens in the general situation for number fields: given a number field $k$, what we can say about the primes which can be equal (or not equal) to norms of some integral ideal of $k$? What about the natural numbers (which can be expressed as norms of some integral ideal of $k$)? More precise questions that I have are the following:

(1) If $m$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers, is it true that $mn$ is not a norm of some integral ideal if and only if at least one of $m$ or $n$ is not a norm of some integral ideal? In other words, is the following equivalence true for every pair of coprime integers $m$,$n$: 
$$mn \text{ is a norm } \iff m \text{ and } n \text{ are both norms}$$
Of course in (1), the condition $\implies$ follows from the multiplicativity of ideal norm, so I just want to know about the backward implication. (The equivalence is true for Gaussian Integers.)

(2) For the Gaussian integers, the primes which are not norms are precisely those of the form $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Can we find some congruence or a set of congruences (in the general situation) on the primes which cannot be norms of some integral ideal of $k$?

(3) Indeed in the context of primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, it is true that the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and the singleton $H \subset G = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q})$ consisting of the automorphism $i \mapsto -i$ satisfy the conditions of the Chebotarev Density Thoerem, that is, $H$ is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$ and it contains the Frobenius conjugacy classes of all primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ (and of these primes only). Can we say something like this in the general context of number fields? That is, given a number field $k$, if $P$ denote the set of primes which cannot be norms of some integral ideal of $k$, is it true that there is some Galois extension $K / \mathbb{Q}$ and some subject $H$ of the Galois group $H = Gal(K/ \mathbb Q)$ such that $H$ is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$ and for all sufficiently large primes $p$, we have the equivalence
$$p \in P \iff \sigma_p \in H$$
(where $\sigma_p$ is again the Frobenius conjugacy class at an unramified integer prime $p$)?

I can see that (3) follows if my first question in (2) has an affirmative answer in the same way as for primes congruent to $3$ mod $4$, that is if the set of primes $p$ which cannot be norms on an integral ideal is expressible as a singe polynomial congruence $p \equiv a \pmod m$ where $\gcd(a,m)=1$ (or by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, in the equivalent form of a finite set of congruences  $p \equiv a_i \pmod{m_i}$ where $\gcd(a_i,m_i)=1 \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$ ), but I am not sure if (2) is true. Also, I was thinking that if (3) were true, then $K$ should be the Galois closure of $k$ over $\mathbb Q$. Does this choice work in general (if (3) is true)?

I would really appreciate results and/or (partial) results  (with proof or a (preferably accessible) reference) and/or counterexamples with regard to the questions above and other results in the general direction considered above, including and not liimited to analytic results (such as the number of natural numbers $N \leq x$ which can be norms of some ideal $\mathfrak{a} \lhd \mathcal{O}_k$). Thanks.

Comment: (1) follows from the existence of factorizations into prime ideals and the fact prime ideals have prime power norm. (2) a prime is a norm of an ideal iff it splits completely in the number field. For abelian extensions there are congruence conditions determining when that happens, but not otherwise, but we do have density results (this is a very special case of Chebotarev). (3) Let $K$ be the normal closure of $k/\mathbb Q$ and let $H$ be the set of nonidentity elements.

Comment: Woops, my reply to (2) is only true if the extension is Galois. But it shows that even in the Galois case this is a difficult question. For (3) we have to modify it too, but the answer should be positive: $p$ is not a norm iff it factors into primes all with inertia degree above $1$, but we can see this factorization from the (conjugacy class of) the Frobenius.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just had a few questions: how do I show that a prime integer is a norm iff it splits completely? Also, I didn't really get the last part, what do you mean by "we can see this factorization from the (conjugacy class of) the Frobenius"?

Comment: These issues are addressed in most introductory texts on algebraic number theory. To answer properly would require someone to write up substantial parts of such a text, so it is best if you just read one of these books yourself.

Comment: @Wojowu and @ Stanley Yao Xiao Got it, thanks a lot.